# SwiftUI: Is it possible to layer these views without each one being scrollable?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am presenting a sheet that will present a slider within a section which is within a form.  I was trying to add my subview `AddDoujin` into this view as well.  But the problem is, is that both views are scrollable and aren't layering on top of each other and seems like it is being added to the bottom (if that makes sense). My goal is to make the `AddDoujin` view right under the slider rather than both being each their own view and both of them being scrollable.  Sorry if this is unclear and you need more information.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestingAddDoujin: View {
//Varaibles
    @State private var InputDoujin:String = ""
    var DoujinApi:DoujinAPI
    @Binding var isPresented:Bool
    @State private var RedoEntry:Bool = false
    var PickerOptions = ["Doujin", "Hentai"]
    @State var PickerSelected = ""
    @State var CurrentSelectionForPicker = 0    
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            NavigationView{
                VStack {
                    ZStack{
                        Form{
                            Section(header: Text("What you you looking for?")) {
                                Picker(selection: $CurrentSelectionForPicker, label: Text("Please select one")) {
                                    ForEach(0..<PickerOptions.count) {
                                        Text("\(self.PickerOptions[$0])")
                                    }
                                }
                                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                                
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                    AddDoujin(DoujinApi: DoujinApi, isPresented: $isPresented)
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestingAddDoujin_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestingAddDoujin(DoujinApi: DoujinAPI(), isPresented: .constant(false))
    }
}
```

<kbd>[image: Screenshot of device which is vertically split in half]</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

It seems like if you just move `AddDoujin(DoujinApi: DoujinApi, isPresented: $isPresented)` right below `.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())` You will get the desired result.

I'm guessing you've tried this. So maybe show and tell us more about what you are trying to accomplish.

btw. In Swift it's not convention to capitalize the first letter of a variable.

Comment: Sorry If I don't explain this correctly.  But currently, it seems like im just adding the Adddoujin view to the bottom of the current view.  My goal is to add it underneath the picker.  I don't want it to be within the section / form , but just underneath.  So I would want it to be the form with the picker then right underneath my other view that his another form and a button and etc, if that makes sense

Comment: Ok I see. Do you have link to a repo? Or can you post the code for ```addDoujin```?